# How to force Vim to open given file as another filetype? (e.g. .txt.gz?)

Tags: filetype, binary-file

Problem:
I have `.glabels` generated files, which are gzipped xml. When I rename file to have suffix `.xml.gz`, then VIM properly recognizes file and it's editable, human readable xml. After edit I have to rename back to original name.

What I try to open e.g. `x.glabels` file without renaming, what happens is that I see binary data. It does not ungzipped it.

How to force Vim from command like to treat given file like `.gz` ?

If possible please make answer more general, to address general problem : how to make Vim , treat file `.extension1` as file `.another_extension` ?

Use case:
http://glabels.org/ uses gzipped xml, so instead of `.glabels` extension, they could use `.xml.gz`.

When I rename file by adding `.txt.gz` or `.xml.gz` extension, VIM properly picks it up.
However with `.glabels` extension it treats files like binary.

Question :
How to force VIM from commandline to open given file (e.g. "x.glabels") like another type (e.g. "x.xml.gz") ?

No Answers:
I know I can make symlink or temporarily rename file. I wonder about VIM flags.

Bonus Addition to answer:
You are welcome to include in your answer nice way of configuring VIM to treat e.g. `.glabels` as `.xml.gz`, but this won't be accepted as full answer, as I look for onliner that I can use on any machine I will have to deal with. Still, information about config might be helpful for other readers (or my main machines;) ).

Comment: Are you referring to how Vim parses the file contents? What flags vim set? `filetype`? Please refine what you mean by "open as another file type"

Comment: @Wolfie I've provided "Problem" paragraph, that I hope clarifies use-case. Question lost not on being concise, but I hope use case is much more clear. If possible, I will be thankful for suggestions of making it more concise.

Comment: `vim -c set filetype=xml.gz [filename]` when starting vim?

Comment: `:h zip-extension`

Comment: If you want both a "one liner" that works on multiple machines, *and* a generic answer that treats A file as a B file (where A and B can be any types! no less), sorry, your request is too "tight" (you want something fast and short for something generic). Otherwise, the above answers and reading `:h new-filetype-scripts` would be enough :P

Answer (score 5):

There are two answers to your question:

## General

In order to open a file, overriding the default filetype detection, you can just specify a `:setf[iletype]` command as part of `:edit`. For example:

```
:edit +setf\ java strange.cpp
```

The default filetype detection does not change an existing filetype, that's how this works. Of course, you can also do this retroactively via `:setl filetype=...`

## Extending the gzip plugin

As a binary format, Vim cannot directly edit [GZIP] archives. The built-in `:help gzip` plugin hooks into the filetype detection in order to transparently handle archives. This is done via `:autocmd`s. If you want to support other file extensions, the default ones (cp. `:autocmd gzip`) need to be extended with the following:

```
autocmd! BufReadPre *.glabels setlocal binary
autocmd! BufRead *.glabels call gzip#read("gzip -S.glabels -dn")
```

Note the `-S.glabels` addition; without this, `gzip` wouldn't know what to do with the file.

Comment: The oneliner, of course, being `echo -e "autocmd! BufReadPre *.glabels setlocal binary\nautocmd! BufRead *.glabels call gzip#read(\"gzip -S.glabels -dn)\" >> .temp & vim -S .temp & rm .temp`, since he asked for a oneliner. Portable!